# In ActiveRecord is there a way to cache `.all` so that it can be used by `.find_by`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a loop that goes through and updates my records based on remote records. So I end up selecting some subset of `19` objects by a two char string key called `symbol`. What I would like to do is reduce the Postgres calls to call the `.all` once and proceed to use the `find_by_symbol` syntax to grab it when I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can just build a hash lookup and handle the "cache" yourself.

`Hash[Object.all.map{|object| [object.symbol, object]}]`

Answer (score 0):

Once you fetch data with `all` it becomes a Ruby object, not a scope, so you need to use methods from Enumerable to fetch it:

```
Example.all.find { |r| r.symbol == 'example' }
```

Where that's analogous to:

```
Example.find_by(symbol: 'example')
```

Likewise:

```
# Ruby Array
Example.all.select(symbol: 'example')

# ActiveRecord scope
Example.where(symbol: 'example')
```

Obviously you can cache the result of `Example.all` and run methods against it instead of re-loading each time.